# Updating in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am leaning how to use Realm and when I try to Update my list I get Index out of range error I am getting the index from my TableView

```
 func updateToDo(toDoEntity: [ToDoEntity] , toDo: String, index: Int ,completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void){
        do {
            self.database.beginWrite()
            toDoEntity[index].toDo = toDo
            self.database.add(toDoEntity, update: false)
            try self.database.commitWrite()
            completion(true)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error While Add New ToDo")
            completion(false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is passed in the `toDoEntity` parameter, unless it is the data source for the table view you can use the index from your table view?

Comment: this is what I am passing in it [ToDoEntity](), and I am using the index from my table view

Comment: You can't pass an empty array and then access a specific index in it. Maybe you meant to append to the array?

Comment: oh, yes you are right I dont notices , Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but there's no need for a completion handler here, since your function is synchronous. You can simply return the boolean value synchronously.